# thread_create_running causes my entire computer to restart on OSX 10.6

Tags: c, macos, reverse-engineering

I'm attempting to write a C program in OSX that will change another program's execution flow, exactly like a debugger would. But before I put all of the "pieces" together, I need to test that each of them work individually first.

- I've successfully used `mach_vm_read_overwrite()` and `mach_vm_write()` to read and write to the stack.
- I've successfully used `thread_get_state()` and `thread_set_state()` to read and write to registers.

All that's left is to use `thread_create_running()` to create a thread in the task to execute my arbitrary function. However, whenever I create a thread, OSX completely crashes and automatically reboots my computer, lol. Can someone explain what is going on in more detail?

Here's my remote program, test.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function1() {
    printf("lol 1\n");
}

void function2() {
    printf("lol 2\n");
}

void function3() {
    printf("lol 3\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    while(1) {
        function1();
        sleep(1);
        function2();
        sleep(1);
        function3();
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my tiny debugger-in-progress:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <mach/mach_traps.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/mach_error.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_types.h>
#include <mach/i386/thread_status.h>

void error(char *msg) {
        printf("error: %s\n", msg);
        exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid;
    mach_port_t eq_task;
    kern_return_t err;
    thread_act_port_array_t thread_list;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;
    x86_thread_state_t x86_state;
    mach_msg_type_number_t sc = x86_THREAD_STATE_COUNT;
    thread_act_t remoteThread;

    // Make sure we have an argument
    if (argc != 2)
        error("requires a PID");
    else
        pid = (pid_t)atoi(argv[1]);

    // Make sure we're root
    if (getuid() && geteuid())
        error("requires root");

    // Get the task port
    err = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &eq_task);
    if ((err != KERN_SUCCESS) || !MACH_PORT_VALID(eq_task))
        error("getting eq task");

    // Suspend the process
    if(task_suspend(eq_task))
        error("suspending the task");

    // Get a list of threads from the port
    if (task_threads(eq_task, &thread_list, &thread_count))
        error("cannot get list of tasks");

    // Get the registers
    if (thread_get_state(thread_list[0], x86_THREAD_STATE, (thread_state_t)&x86_state, &sc))
        error("getting state from thread");

    // Create a new thread
    err = thread_create_running(eq_task, x86_THREAD_STATE, (thread_state_t)&x86_state, x86_THREAD_STATE_COUNT, &remoteThread);

    // BLACK SCREEN AND CRASH

    // Resume the process again
    if(task_resume(eq_task))
        error("resuming the task");

}
```

Comment: This may not be your only issue, but I have always found that creating a thread in another task while that task is suspended causes it to crash. In addition, the crash log is often of use to see which thread actually caused the issue.

Comment: Even if the thread is not suspended, my computer still restarts.

Where are the crash logs located?

Comment: You can view them in the Console app.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your trying to execute this in an XD bit, unless your running rocking an AMD instead of an intel.  Then it would be NX opposed to XD.  This would cause the application or even the entire computer to crash.